# Alternate webform UI is buggy

Tags: webforms

I have been experimenting with the Webform Alternate UI module for Drupal Webforms. As you would know it requires a few excess modules like options_element, ux element and form builder. The thing is, the webform alternate UI shows up but it does not really work when I attempt to drag and drop the form fields onto it. Its' clearly buggy. And it seems like it has some unfixed issues persistent along with it.

I want to check on stackoverflow with anyone who has played along with the webform Alternate UI and found it to be buggy and has a fix for it?

Thanks much

Comment: The way to fix a contributed module is to provide a patch for the module, or wait somebody provides a patch that is then applied from one of the maintainers. The question as it is is not acceptable; if it were about alternative modules to use (which is what nicoz's answer is about), then it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I have found Webform Alternate UI to be quite buggy as well and have opted to use just the [Form Builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) module by itself, which gives a good UI for users to build forms (and is not buggy).

Comment: does the form builder module act as a content type? I in particular am attracted to the UI of the Webform module because it makes it easy to clone fields etc.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "act as a content type"?

Comment: well enabled webforms for a specific content type only!

Comment: Still unsure at what you are getting at. However, the form builder module only enhances the UI of the webform module. so whatever the webform module does is what is available. The form builder just makes it a drag and drop UI.

Comment: it seems like this is more of what webform alternate UI module does, not the form builder module. I enabled form builder UI but did not see any changes to the default webform alternate modules. Thanks !!

Comment: Just tried alternative_UI and wasn't very happy with it. Flow below is when using webform 4 beta1, Webform UI alpha6. When Webform UI alpha6 is enabled, I get this notice: Notice: Use of undefined constant COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED - assumed 'COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED' in webform_alt_ui_enable() (line 21 of /Applications/AMPPS/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/webform_alt_ui/webform_alt_ui.install). When editing an existing webform, I lost the ability to edit the webform components. I also get this notice when accessing the webform node edit page:: Notice: Undefined index: menu in _webform_alt_ui_webform_sett